# ArgumentError in Devise/registrations#new wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to Rails. I've installed the newest Devise gem and I'm getting this error:

```
ArgumentError in Devise/registrations#new

Showing /Users/Malone/Sites/todos/app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb where line #3 raised:
Wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
Extracted source (around line #3):
1: <h2>Sign up</h2>
2:
3: <%= form_for(resource_name, resource,: URL => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
4: <%= f.error_messages %>
5: <p><%= f.label: email %></p>
6: <p><%= f.text_field: email %></p>
```

Not sure what other information you'd need to help me. But let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<%= form_for(resource_name, resource, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

To

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

for solving your issue try this

```
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_messages %>
    <p><%= f.label: email %></p>
    <p><%= f.text_field: email %></p>
    ....
    ....
  <% end %>
```